# Missing client_id with Devise and Facebook-Omniauth

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

Here is my initializers/devise.rb code for Facebook:

```
require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, "app_key", "app_secret"
```

And I have added:

`devise :omniauthable` into the model I want to be able to use Facebook with.

When I click on this link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

I get:

An **OAuthException** with message: `"message": "Missing client_id parameter.",`

Notice that the app_key and app_secret are the ones that I can see on my Facebook app but I haven't put here.

On the URL that is redirected when clicking the Sign in with facebook link I see that the client_id parameter is empty:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id&

But why?

Comment: what did you do to fix this? I am getting the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never done it directly with devise. But this also works well with devise.

[Omniauth podcast on RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1)

Alternatively, If you still want to stick with using devise built-in omiauth, try to find a way to provide it the app id and app secret. I'm pretty sure that you have to provide it in devise.rb in config/initializers/

Comment: Add this in your devise.rb config file

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your devise.rb file

```
require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET"
```

Dont forget to restart your app for the changes to take place.